# How to solve the heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

We consider the following initial-boundary value problem:
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
u_t-u_{xx} &= -u^{q} & x \in \Omega, t > 0 \newline
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial\nu} &= u^{p} & x \in \partial \Omega, t > 0 \newline
u(x,0) &= u_0(x) & x \in \Omega
\end{align}
\end{cases}
where $0 < p, q < \infty$, $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth $\partial \Omega$, $\nu$ is the outward normal, $0 \le u_0(x) \le M$, and $\frac{\partial u_0}{\partial\nu}=u^{p}_0$ on  $\partial \Omega$.

What's the method to solve $u(x,t)$?

Comment: @Mattos The equation isn't linear (because of the right side), so the eqaution on $v$ won't be homogeneous.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Ah how embarrassing, even though it is clearly a $u$ on the RHS, I've been reading the problem as something like $u_{t} - u_{xx} = f^{q}(x,t)$ the entire time.